# Consistent touch target size on High DPI mobile device ? (WebApp scenario)

Tags: css, web-applications, mobile, touch

Considering a css pixel is not a device pixel on high DPI device, predict and manage touch target size across these devices have been a headache for me.

For example, say I have a Web App with viewport meta `"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"`, on iPad (**9.7 inch** screen) in landscape mode, viewport is set to **1024px**, and **50px** (in css) is roughly **1cm** in physical size.

However for device such as Nexus 7 (**7 inch** screen), viewport would be set to **966px**, thus **50px** (in css) is only about **0.7cm** in physical size. (Not to mention a growing list of High DPI device that I may not get my hands on)

Different guideline varies on [recommeneded touch target size](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1085), but I tend to prefer around 1cm to allow for human error.

**Is there a best practice for such scenario**? the idea described in [Let's Get Physical (Units)](http://smus.com/physical-units/) is the closest I found via google, but far from production ready.

Answer (score 0):

Start using em or percentages instead of px.

This is probably going to be what pushes everyone over the line.